# Confusion on expression of time complexity with geometric series

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have this code:

```
int count = 0;
    for (int i = N; i > 0; i /= 2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
```

Its time complexity is ***O(n)*** and I already understood why, but I don’t understand why they drop the n from this mathematical expression resulting of analyzing the code:

```
n(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + …)
```

The inside-brackets can be seen as log(n) so it is not n(log(n))? (only the expression, without considering the algorithm).

For example I was analyzing the Sieve of Eratosthenes and I get a similar expression:

```
n/2 + n/3 + n/5 + n/7 + … = n(1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 +…)
```

So what it is inside brackets can bee seen as *loglogn* and with the n outside, finally it’s: ***nloglogn***

What’s the difference between:

```
n(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + …)
```

to get here ***O(nloglogn)***

and getting from here:

```
n(1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 +…)
```

***O(n)***?

Answer (score 0):

The first series converges to 2: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+1%2F2+%2B+1%2F4+%2B+1%2F8+%2B... hence it boils down to O(n).

The second series is harder to analyse but can be proven to be equivalent (or at least, not as fast as) to log(log(n)), hence the result O(nlog(logn)). Example proof: https://medium.com/@chenfelix/time-complexity-sieve-of-eratosthenes-fb0184da81dc .

Comment: Sorry, the attempt at the second link is equally unacceptable. Both original link and the link you've changed to use `sum[1, infty] 1/n` which is _infinite_, and then take its logarithm, which is also _infinite_. The real proof is much more subtle.

Comment: @user58697 Feel free to share any better source. This one is definitely acceptable in this context, since the point is that it's not trivial, which our discussion here additionally proves. Also, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes)  at least, taking logarithm for both sides is what Euler did as well, so it's surely good enough. But of course I'll read any better source you can provide, especially one that claims that's it's always incorrect to take logarithm of both infinite sides. Otherwise - good day/night to you :-)